# Sort Parameter for 7 different fields in CR 10

Tags: crystal-reports

> I am attempting to write a sort field parameter for all of my 7 fields in CR10. I have followed the directions in the help section - Define sort order using parameter fields - and just tried 3 fields for the moment. I can't get either to work properly and I'm not sure if this is at all possible.
>
> Here is what I have.
>   My report originally was grouped by 1 Payer ID and then 2 Claim Number. I removed those groups and moved my fields into the details section. Here are the fields:
>
> ```
> `Claim#
> Payer ID
> Payer Name
> Account#
> Name
> Billed Amt
> Date`
> ```
>
> I created a parameter called Sort Field, selected string and made sure my min and max were set to one. Placed the following into the prompting text:
>
> ```
> `C = Claim
> I = Payer ID
> P = Payer Name
> A = Account#
> N = Name
> B = Billed Amt
> Date is Default`
> ```
>
> I created a formula and called it Sort. I have tried this as stated above with all 7 fields and also only 3 fields - my main focus is all of the fields.
>
> ```
> `If {?SortField} = "C" 
> Then totext({table.ClaimNumber},"########")
> ElseIf {?SortField} = "I" 
> Then totext({table.ID_Payer},"########")
> ElseIf {?SortField} = "P" 
> Then {table.PayerName}
> ElseIf {?SortField} = "A" 
> Then totext({table.Account},"#######")
> ElseIf {?SortField} = "N" 
> Then {table.Last_Name}
> ElseIf {?SortField} = "B" 
> Then totext({table.ClaimGrossCharge},"#########.##")
> Else totext({table.SubmittedDate},"")`
> ```
>
> I then placed `@Sort` into the report header and suppressed in the section expert. I also included the following formula in the Record Selection:
>
> ```
> `{table.SubmittedDate} >= {?Submitted Date From} and
> {table.SubmittedDate} <= {?Submitted Date To} and
> {@Sort} = {?SortField}`
> ```
>
> Finally, I made sure that the `@Sort` formula was selected in the record sort expert.
>
> I run the report and get nothing. I comment out `{@Sort} = {?SortField}` in the Record Selection and I get data. Although, the data is duplicating since it is not grouped as it was originally.
>
> Can this be done? This option would be amazing for our clients and I have a feeling it can work but I believe I am missing something. Is my `@Sort` formula correct or does it need to be adjusted? I am attempting to make sure all of the fields are to text since I selected string in the parameter.
>
> Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit lenghty question but will try to answer to the extent I understand.

I am assuming `sort(From formula that you have written)` you mean display only those values that client has selected and supress the rest and my answer will support this idea. If this is not you are looking for let me know will try to answer to the extent possible.

1. You shouldn't be using the `{@Sort} = {?SortField}` in record selection formula since this will be directly fired in database and as per your design this won't return any data as you parameter values doesn't match with the data in database.So remove this part from record selection.
2. Do place your `sort` formula in report header as it doesn't fetch full data in header and its of no use to supress.
3. As you place all fields in detail section you can use your created `Sort` formula in detail section in place of original fields which will do the job as per the user selection.
4. If you are getting the duplicate data then you need to check links to the tables or check the option `Select Distinct Data` in database tab which will remove duplicate data